# Javascript writing a file

Tags: javascript, saving-data, local-files

I am trying to get this to write to a local file on the server and I am running into so issues. I got it to write a file and then read in a browser, but I can not put a link to it so others can run the pop up banner with out entering the info. Here is the javascript I am working with. I know that using marquee is not the best thing but this is a required thing. Also this only needs to work on a local network not internet facing. This will be running on the server and a link to the file on the server is what is provided to every one else. And more so the page will be running from the same folder. Sorry about that. Thank you for the help.

*SOLVED* I found my answer to my issue here. https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js

```
                ---------------Test.js file-----------
function openWin() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=2000,height=200,location=no,notoolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,left=0,top=950");
var text = document.getElementById('notebox');
var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
var image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
var imlink = document.getElementById('imlink');
var background = document.getElementById('background');
var fontsize = document.getElementById('fontsize');
var fontcolor = document.getElementById('fontcolor');
var fonttype = document.getElementById('fonttype');
var fontspeed = document.getElementById('fontspeed');
    myWindow.document.write("<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left' scrollamount='"  + fontspeed.value +  "' BGCOLOR='"  + background.value +  "'><h1 style='font-size:"  + fontsize.value +  "px;color:"  + fontcolor.value +  ";font-family:" + fonttype.value + ";'><img src='"  + image1.value +  "' style='width:100px;height:100px;' > "  + text.value +  " <img src='"  + image2.value +  "' style='width:100px;height:100px;' ></h1></marquee>"); 
   myWindow.document.close()
}
function SaveDatFileBro(localstorage) {
   localstorage.root.getFile("Banner.html", {create: true});
}


--------------------------------Banner.html---------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="Test.js"></script>

<table style="margin:0px auto 0px auto"> 
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value=" Open Banner" onclick="openWin();SaveDatFileBro()"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="notebox" value="Enter Notification" size="120"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value=" Save Banner" onclick="SaveDatFileBro()"/></td>
        <td>Font Color:<input type="text" id="fontcolor" value="Red"/> Font Type:<input type="text" id="fonttype" value="Times New Roman"/> Font Size:<input type="text" id="fontsize" value="130" /> Scroll Speed:<input type="text" id="fontspeed" value="25" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Background Color:<input type="text" id="background" value="White" />  Leading Image:<input type="text" id="image1" value="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/4/44/White_square.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/200?cb=20061003200043" /> Trailing Image:<input type="text" id="image2" value="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/4/44/White_square.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/200?cb=20061003200043" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to store data on the server, you need to run code on the server to save the file.

Comment: It will be running on the server but at the moment I can not get it to save to my local machine when I am running it.

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible. Your browser has absolutely no access to the file system on the server.

If you want to write to the server's file system, you need a server-side process that listens for data submitted to it from the browser over HTTP.